# Django AJAX "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attrs is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, typeerror

When I tap the anchor tag to send the data, I get this error **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attrs is not a function**.

I did `console.log($(this))`, the output is **[object Object]**.

I also did `console.log(JSON.stringify($(this)))`, the output is **{"0":{},"length":1}**

***HTML***,
My anchor tag:

```
                <a href="{% url 'my-site' slug=object.anotherObject.slug %}" id="update-done"
                    data-donePk="{{object.pk}}" 
                >Done</a>
```

***JS***, My AJAX

```
    $(document).on('click', '#update-done', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let confirmation = confirm("Are you sure you want to make done?");
    
        if (confirmation) {
            console.log("this: " + JSON.stringify($(this)))
            alert($(this))

            // Error comes from this line below
            var objectPk = $(this).attrs('data-donePk')
    
            var makeDone = 'post'
            $.ajax({
                
                url: "/site/make_done/",
                data: {
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': "{{ csrf_token }}",
                    "objectPk":objectPk,
                    "makeDone": makeDone,
                },
    
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
    
                cache: false,
    
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
            })
            
        }
        
    
        
    });
```

Comment: You want to use [`$(this).attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) not `$(this).attrs`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule there is a library called [jquery.attrs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.attrs), but the original author didn't mention this. I couldn't see any problem otherwise as the person already converted `$this` into a jQuery object

Comment: @OluwafemiSule That took away the error, Thanks. 